# Excel VBA- Browse and open the files, paste the open files in macro sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Am trying to automate, browse the files through search button and open the files and it should be pasted in the next sheet of my macro sheet. Pleae help to do in excel vba.

I try to open two files and i need to compare the files.

Comment: To clarify the question:
1. Are you comparing the same two files each time?
2. Do you want to copy/paste the contents of the two files into your macro workbook, into two existing sheets? Or two new sheets?
3. In what way do you want to compare them?

Comment: I need to copy/paste the content of the two files into my macro workbook. Through browse button only i need to pick the path and paste the files in macro workbook.

Answer (score 2):

This code will let you browse to a selected file and then open it

```
Sub OpenFile()
Dim strFileToOpen As Variant

strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

If strFileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen
End If

End Sub
```

This will get you started.  Once it is open, you can write code to copy the sheet(s) into your macro file.